# Iptables forward with running Squid proxy

Tags: networking, iptables, squid

My topology include 3 hosts (client, squid proxy and server).

```
Client: eth1: 192.168.1.3/24
Squid proxy: eth1 192.168.30.3/24,  eth2 192.168.31.3/24
Server: eth1: 192.168.10.3/24
```

On host (squid proxy) I have set up some rules to block download specific files from host -server (wget).

The traffic (on host-squid proxy) is redirected with iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

(squid.conf > http_port 3128 accel allow-direct)

The problem is, the traffic doesn’t reach server-host and it stops on squid-proxy host (tcpdump shows: „code 404, message File not found”).

While the above rule is disabled, everything is working.

How can I make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: EDIT. "http_port 3128 transparent" fixed the problem.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, you should post your answer below.